# I have probleme with session state serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, naudio

I used this code to serialize an object

```
public void play(string url, string i)
    {
      MP3StreamingPanel mp3=new MP3StreamingPanel ( );
      mp3.play ( url );
      HttpContext . Current . Session [ i ] = mp3;
```

then when i want to get it, some value in the mp3 attribute still 'null'

```
  MP3StreamingPanel mp3=new MP3StreamingPanel ( );
  mp3 = HttpContext . Current . Session [ i ] as MP3StreamingPanel;
```

and this is the MP3StreamingPanel class

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MP3StreamingPanel 
        {

        enum StreamingPlaybackState
            {
            Stopped ,
            Playing ,
            Buffering ,
            Paused
            }




[NonSerialized]
public HttpWebRequest webRequest;
[NonSerialized]
public System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System . Timers . Timer ( );
public SerializableVolumeWaveProvider16 volumeProvider;
delegate void ShowErrorDelegate ( string message );
public string gurl="";
public SerializableBufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
public SerializableWaveOut waveOut;
private  volatile StreamingPlaybackState playbackState;
public volatile bool fullyDownloaded;

public MP3StreamingPanel ( )
    {
    }

public void InitTimer ( )
    {
    timer1 . Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler ( timer1_Tick );
    timer1 . Interval = 250; // in miliseconds
    timer1 . Start ( );
    }
public void timer1_Tick ( object sender , ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
    if ( playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState . Stopped )
        {
        if ( this . waveOut == null && this . bufferedWaveProvider != null )
            {
            Debug . WriteLine ( "Creating WaveOut Device" );
            this . waveOut = CreateWaveOut ( );
            waveOut . PlaybackStopped += waveOut_PlaybackStopped;
            this . volumeProvider = new SerializableVolumeWaveProvider16 ( `enter code here`bufferedWaveProvider );
            waveOut . Init ( volumeProvider );

            }
        else if ( bufferedWaveProvider != null )
            {
            var bufferedSeconds = bufferedWaveProvider . BufferedDuration . TotalSeconds;

            if ( bufferedSeconds < 0.5 && this . playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Playing && !this . fullyDownloaded )
                {
                this . playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Buffering;
                waveOut . Pause ( );
                Debug . WriteLine ( String . Format ( "Paused to buffer, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}" , waveOut . PlaybackState ) );
                }
            else if ( bufferedSeconds > 4 && this . playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Buffering )
                {
                waveOut . Play ( );
                Debug . WriteLine ( String . Format ( "Started playing, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}" , waveOut . PlaybackState ) );
                this . playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Playing;
                }
            else if ( this . fullyDownloaded && bufferedSeconds == 0 )
                {
                Debug . WriteLine ( "Reached end of stream" );
                stop ( );
                }
            }

        }
    }


public void StreamMP3 ( object state )
    {
    this . fullyDownloaded = false;
    string url = ( string ) state;
    webRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest . Create ( url );
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    try
        {
        resp = ( HttpWebResponse ) webRequest . GetResponse ( );
        }
    catch ( WebException e )
        {
        if ( e . Status != WebExceptionStatus . RequestCanceled )
            {
            Console.WriteLine ( e . Message );
            }
        return;
        }
    byte[] buffer = new byte [ 16384 * 4 ]; 

    IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;
    try
        {
        using ( var responseStream = resp . GetResponseStream ( ) )
            {
            var readFullyStream = new ReadFullyStream ( responseStream );
            do
                {
                if ( bufferedWaveProvider != null && bufferedWaveProvider . BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider . BufferedBytes < bufferedWaveProvider . WaveFormat . AverageBytesPerSecond / 4 )
                    {
                    Debug . WriteLine ( "Buffer getting full, taking a break" );
                    Thread . Sleep ( 500 );
                    }
                else
                    {
                    Mp3Frame frame = null;
                    try
                        {
                        frame = Mp3Frame . LoadFromStream ( readFullyStream );
                        }
                    catch ( EndOfStreamException )
                        {
                        this . fullyDownloaded = true;

                        break;
                        }
                    catch ( WebException )
                        {

                        break;
                        }
                    if ( decompressor == null )
                        {
                        WaveFormat waveFormat = new Mp3WaveFormat ( frame . SampleRate , frame . ChannelMode == ChannelMode . Mono ? 1 : 2 , frame . FrameLength , frame . BitRate );
                        decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor ( waveFormat );
                        this . bufferedWaveProvider = new SerializableBufferedWaveProvider ( decompressor . OutputFormat );
                        this . bufferedWaveProvider . BufferDuration = TimeSpan . FromSeconds ( 20 ); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                        }
                    int decompressed = decompressor . DecompressFrame ( frame , buffer , 0 );
                     bufferedWaveProvider . AddSamples ( buffer , 0 , decompressed );
                    }

                } while ( playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState . Stopped );
            Debug . WriteLine ( "Exiting" );
            decompressor . Dispose ( );
            }
        }
    finally
        {
        if ( decompressor != null )
            {
            decompressor . Dispose ( );
            }
        }
    }

public void play ( string url )
    {
    if ( playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Stopped )
        {
            playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Buffering;
            this . bufferedWaveProvider = null;
            ThreadPool . QueueUserWorkItem ( new WaitCallback ( StreamMP3 ) , url );
            gurl = url;
            InitTimer ( );
            timer1 . Enabled = true;
        }
    else if ( playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Paused )
        {
             playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Buffering;
        }
    }

public void stop ( )
    {

    if ( playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState . Stopped )
        {
        if ( !fullyDownloaded )
            {
            webRequest . Abort ( );
            }
        this . playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Stopped;
        if ( waveOut != null )
            {
            waveOut . Stop ( );
            waveOut . Dispose ( );
            waveOut = null;
            }
        timer1 . Enabled = false;
        // n.b. streaming thread may not yet have exited
        Thread . Sleep ( 500 );
         }
    }



public SerializableWaveOut CreateWaveOut ( )
    {
    return new SerializableWaveOut ( );

    }


public void pause ( )
    {
    if ( playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Playing || playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState . Buffering )
        {
        waveOut . Pause ( );
        Debug . WriteLine ( String . Format ( "User requested Pause, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}" , waveOut . PlaybackState ) );
        playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState . Paused;
        }
    }

public void buttonStop_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
    stop ( );
    }

private void waveOut_PlaybackStopped ( object sender , StoppedEventArgs e )
    {
    Debug . WriteLine ( "Playback Stopped" );
    if ( e . Exception != null )
        {
        MessageBox . Show ( String . Format ( "Playback Error {0}" , e . Exception . Message ) );
        }
    }
}
```

for `SerializableVolumeWaveProvider16` , `SerializableBufferedWaveProvider`and `SerializableWaveOut`  are classes that I declared as [Serializable]
but i can't get there values after serialization

Comment: Clarify "can't get there [sic] values after serialization" please? do you get an object back? or a `null`? or...? what happens? Also: anecdotally, that's a very... *unusual* code-spacing policy you seem to have adopted; *unique*, perhaps. What values are `null` ? is it perhaps those marked `[NonSerialized]`? or...?

Comment: the null values are: bufferedWaveProvider , volumeProvider , waveOut , and webRequest

Comment: you should not expect `webRequest` to be serialized - it is marked `[NonSerialized]` - also; serializing an in-flight request makes no sense anyway. Re the other 3; were they actually non-null when you stored it? Additionally, what is the session-state provider you are using? it might not even be using serialization...

Comment: yes actualyy when i use in-proc session mode it work normally but when I use stateServer mode i don't get the result that i want

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all to serialize these classes. You can't use NAudio on the server to play sound in a web browser if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkHeath why can't I use NAudio on the server to play sound in a web browser !!!

Comment: because NAudio plays sound out of the soundcard on the server. You need to use the HTML 5 audio tag, or flash or silverlight to play sound in the browser.

Comment: ok,, my work is that i'm supposed to create a radio server that provide stream for client,,,, how shall i do it?

Answer (score 2):

### Do not store complex objects in session / cache

The object you are storing in session here is complicated and has many moving parts. The main mistake people make when using cache and session is storing "active" objects (heck, it has a timer, a web-request, etc). You should only store (in session, cache, or on a file-system etc) cold hard inactive *data*. I strongly suggest you create a separate DTO layer that just contains *data*; for example:

```
public class Something {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int SomeNumber {get;set;}
    public byte[] Blob {get;set;}
    // ... more simple data values
}
```

You would ideally populate store / retrieve something of this form; simple, easy to understand, etc. Then map to/from this DTO model and your *actual* model as you need to.

Actually, an even better idea would be to make the DTO immutable; this will avoid complications if your provider doesn't actually serialize, but keeps things in memory. Because otherwise the following is ambiguous:

```
var obj = session[key] as Something;
if(obj != null) {
    obj.Name = "new name";
}
```

with a *serializing* provider, that change will not usually be reflected unless explicitly stored again at the end; with an *in-memory* provider, that will be visible to all other callers immediately (keeping in mind that users can have multiple concurrent requests).

If you move to a DTO-based model when using session/cache/etc, you will be *forced* to write code that is understandable and obviously correct. Rather than "sometimes work for a reason that nobody can guess".